# WooCommerce - How do i remove the ability to go to product page when clicking on short description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce on WordPress with a Theme i bought, and i want to remove the functionality of short description to be unclickable on my site.

Here is an example of what i am talking about :
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOHrs.png)

When i hover over the description it becomes clickable and sends me to the product page, and i don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. But with what I understood...

There is a hyperlink that make you go to product page when you click on a product/description that it is on the loop.
The location of that link can change depending on the Theme actually.

But in my theme I remove mine with these hooks.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
```

If that don't work. Then it may need a different Hook... 
Then more information about your theme is going to be needed.

Comment: Well.. i don't even know where to put these lines at, can you specify where you put em?

Comment: Inside your functions.php file. Thats how Woocommerce works, with Hooks to run code inside the Theme.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer i had to go to Settings > Permalink Settings and then i had to choose Shop base.